# Prompt choice for bot framework

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, bots

I have two issues.

1. My `retryPrompt` is not working. Inputs by user are matched to an intent from LUIS instead of re-prompt of question.

   **Desire**: When user enter "5", it will re-prompt the question.

   **Actual**: When user enter "5", it will match with LUIS intent.
2. Is it possible to validate the input by user before determining to re-prompt the question or starting another dialog?

   **Desire**: if user enters "carrot", it will send a message "carrot is under veg" followed by the re-prompt of the same question. However, if user enters "5", it will re-prompt the user with the same question.

Please refer below for my code.

```
var luisAppId = process.env.LuisAppId;
var luisAPIKey = process.env.LuisAPIKey;
var luisAPIHostName = process.env.LuisAPIHostName || 'southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';

const LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + 
luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey;

// Create a recognizer that gets intents from LUIS, and add it to the bot
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
bot.recognizer(recognizer);

bot.dialog('pets', [
function (session, args, next) {
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'which pet do you prefer?\n1. rabbit?\n2. dog?\n3. cat?\n', ['1', '2', '3'], {
        retryPrompt: "sorry please pick.\n1. rabbit?\n2. dog?\n3. cat?",
        maxRetries: 1
    });
},
function (session, args, next) {
    if (args.response) {
        var choice = args.response.entity;
        switch (choice) {
            case '1':
                session.replaceDialog('rabbit');
                break;
            case '2':
                session.replaceDialog('dog');
                break;
            case '3':
                session.replaceDialog('cat');
                break;
            default: 
                session.send('sorry!!');
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        session.send("Invalid");
    }
}
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The recognizer's .onEnabled method can be used to disable the LUIS recognizer:

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl)
.onEnabled(function (context, callback) {
    var enabled = context.dialogStack().length === 0;
    callback(null, enabled); 
});
```

You can also check the dialogData's option's choice's to determine if the current text is a valid option for the current dialog:

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModel)
.onEnabled(function (context, callback) {
    var enabled = context.dialogStack().length === 0;
    if(context.dialogData && context.dialogData.options && context.dialogData.options.choices){
        if(!context.dialogData.options.choices.includes(context.message.text)){
            //text is not in current dialog options
        }
    }

    callback(null, enabled); 
});
```